# Pointer for new function returning 0

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

Why is my pointer 'pTwo' in main() returning half of a function (the name *'fiddo'*) but returning 0 for the age which looks to be an integer of the number 19?

*Dog *pTwo = new Dog("Fiddo", 19);*

Below I have some objects that are working... Like SetDogName, and SetAge

Is Getage() a proper member? It returns *'this'* -> age

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    class Dog { 
       private:
        std::string aDogName;
         int age;

       public:
        Dog(); //constructor 
        Dog(std::string dogName, int age);
        ~Dog(); //destructor

        void SetDogName(std::string dogName); //setter
        std::string GetDogName();  //getter

        void SetAge(int age);
        int Getage(); //integer function

        void SayHello();  

    };

    class Person { 
        public:

        Person();

        ~Person(); 

        void SayHello();

    };

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    Dog::Dog() { //dog constructor


    }


    Dog::Dog(std::string dogName, int age) { 
        aDogName = dogName;
        age = age; 
        }


    Dog::~Dog() { //dog destructor


    }

    void Dog::SetDogName(std::string dogName) {
        this->aDogName = dogName;

    }

    std::string Dog::GetDogName() { 
        return this->aDogName;

    }

    void Dog::SetAge(int age) { 
        this->age = age;
    }

    int Dog::Getage() { 
        return this->age; 
    }

    void Dog::SayHello() { 
        std::cout << "Woof!" << std::endl;
        }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Person::Person () { 


    }

    Person::~Person()
    { 


    }

     void Person::SayHello() {

        std::cout << "Hello." << std::endl;

    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    int main()
    { 


        Dog *pTwo = new Dog("Fiddo", 19);

        std::cout << pTwo->GetDogName() << std::endl;
        std::cout << pTwo->Getage() << std::endl;





      Dog d; 
      Person p;

    d.SetDogName("Puppy");
    std::cout << d.GetDogName() << std::endl;

    d.SetAge(16); 
    std::cout << d.Getage() << std::endl;



      p.SayHello();
       d.SayHello();



    }
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ - the fraction of your code actually relevant to the question is pretty small.

Comment: Don't use `new`. Just declare `Dog Dog2("Fido", 19);`  Forget you ever heard of `new`.  `New` is bad for you. Dispense with the->pointers also.

Answer (score 3):

```
age = age;
```

Your problem is right here. The paramter `age` overshadows the member variable, so you're just setting the parameter to itself.

Use field initialization lists, rename your parameter or use `this->`* to specify the member to fix this:

```
Dog::Dog(std::string dogName, int age) : aDogName(dogName), age(age) { }
```

---

<sup>*Thanks to @DrewDormann!</sup>

Comment: ...or qualify it with `this->`